# GPRS Setting in mobile Application its self

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, gprs

Can i save automatically GPRS setting when i am installing the Java ME application.
Any one have any experience please share.

Comment: do you mean to access APN using your Java ME Code ?

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't have this.

What you can do is, Try making connection if it fails prompt user to make active connection available to application.

Comment: you said that ,suppose my application is communicating with server,on that time i change my connection setting manually,mobile browser will not work ,after the changes...j2me application will work if you are not exit the application...please replay if my understanding is right or not...

Comment: yes thats what I said. handle `ConnectionNotFoundExceptoin`  and prompt user to supply active connection.

Comment: So what is your question now ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't change the GPRS settings programmatically. We don't have the permission for accessing those things. So you have to change manually the GPRS settings before starting your application.

Comment: i want to confirm one thing ..when i am starting the application GPRS setting is with bsnl and application is communicating successfully with server.after that i minimize my application and change internet setting from airtel,airtel is not working in my mobile and i have checked with my browser and confirms internet is not working..and then go to my application and maximize and use the connectivity its working in application..my application is working only because of active cannectivity or not..i want to confirm..please help...

Comment: Have you checked on emulator or real device? Because its not possible without GPRS connection.